# QStringList in QT c++

Tags: c++, qt

I want to assign each item of a string list to another string list, like:

```
stringlist_1 = ("k*k1*k2" , "s*s1*s2" , "b*b1*b2")
```

I want to make them like this :

```
stringlist_2 = ("k","k","k2")

stringlist_3 = ("s","s1","s2")
```

etc..

how can I make that?
I tray to use this code

```
for (int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++)
{
    QStringList d = stringlist_1.value(i).split("*");
    qDebug()<< d ; 
}
```

I use a `for` loop becuase my list it is very big, but 
the problem is with storing all strings of primary list in same stringlist (d).
How can I let a `fo`r loop change the stringlist which assigned to it in each loop?

Is there another way I could achieve that?

Comment: Create a `QVector<QStringList> lists;` before the loop, then do `lists.append(d);` inside the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a vector of string lists:

```
#include <QtCore>

QVector<QStringList> splitTerms(const QStringList & source)
{
   QVector<QStringList> result;
   result.reserve(source.count());
   for (auto src : source)
      result.append(src.split(QChar('*'), QString::SkipEmptyParts));
   return result;
}

int main() {
   qDebug() << splitTerms(QStringList{"k*k1*k2", "s*s1*s2", "b*b1*b2"});
}
```

Output:

```
QVector(("k", "k1", "k2"), ("s", "s1", "s2"), ("b", "b1", "b2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just split it and assign again?

```
 for (int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++)
 {
     QStringList d = stringlist_1.value(i).split("*");
     qDebug()<< d ;
+    foreach (const QString &s, d) {
+        QStringList dd;
+        dd << s;
+        qDebug() << dd;
+    }
 }
```